# Swift: Help solve 'Key path value type '_' cannot be converted to contextual type '_''

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

Im trying to view JSON Data from a contacts API in a list using Swift. This is the code I've got, and I am getting one error on the `List(fetch.contacts, response: \.response) { contact in` line stating:

> Key path value type '*' cannot be converted to contextual type '*'

I have been lost on how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Full code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct Response: Codable {
    struct Contacts: Codable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let updated_date: String
    }
    struct Pagination_Data: Codable {
        public let skip: Int
        public let limit: Int
        public let total: Int
    }
    public let response = UUID().uuidString
    public let data: [Contacts]
    public let pagination: Pagination_Data
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case pagination = "pagination"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchContacts()
    struct Contacts: Codable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let updated_date: String
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.contacts, response: \.response) { contact in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(contact.data.first_name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class FetchContacts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contacts: Response
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "LINK")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let contactData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: contactData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.contacts = decodedData
                    
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(decodedData)
                        
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

JSON Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Lewis",
            "last_name": "Hamilton",
            "updated_date": "2021-07-06"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Sebastian",
            "last_name": "Vettel",
            "updated_date": "2021-07-01"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "skip": 0,
        "limit": 10,
        "total": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model is pretty confusing.

If the data to be displayed is the contacts array the `Published` object must be

```
@Published var contacts = [Response.Contacts]()
```

and populate it

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.contacts = decodedData.data
...
```

---

Then adopt `Identifiable` to `Contacts` in `Response`

```
struct Contacts: Codable, Identifiable { ...
```

The `Contacts` struct in the view is pointless.

---

And the `List` is supposed to be

```
List(fetch.contacts) { contact in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(contact.first_name)
    }
}
```

Please conform to the Swift naming convention that property and variable names are *camelCased*. You can convert the keys with the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy. And it's less confusing to name `Contacts` in singular form `Contact`. Each instance is **one** contact.

Comment: You've fixed the issue, thanks so much! Sorry about the model being confusing and the incorrect naming convention, I'm new and am learning on the go. This is just a project task. Also the Contacts struct in view was a mistake, wasn't meant to be there. Again thanks!